# Trying to compare date picker time to current time ios

Tags: ios, nsdate

Im trying to compare a `UIDatePickers` chosen time to the current time. I would preferably like to compare the `UIDatePickers` chosen time to the time on the current device. This is what I have tried but it is not accurate at all.

```
NSDate * date = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"DatePicker.date %@ <= date %@",self.DatePicker.date,date);

if (self.DatePicker.date<=date) {

    UIAlertView * alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"Choose a time in the future." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    return;

}
```

And it logs out;

```
self.DatePicker.date 2014-09-12 15:15:00 +0000 <= date 2014-09-12 15:03:29 +0000
```

And shows the AlertView

This clocks seem to be an hour off also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use standard comparison operators such as `==` or `<=`, etc. with objects. You need to compare using appropriate methods such as `compare:`.

```
if ([self.DatePicker.date compare:date] == NSOrderedDescending) {
}
```

I may have that backwards. It may need to be `NSOrderedAscending`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the `timeZone` property of your picker to the current timeZone.
2. When comparing `NSDate` objects, you should use `compare:`